# How do I bind a pool (without too much boilerplate) in Guice?

Tags: java, scala, dependency-injection, guice, pool

I have a common interface like so:

```
trait Thing {
  ...
}
```

And implementations like so:

```
class ThingA extends Thing {
  ...
}

class ThingB extends Thing {
  ...
}
```

Which one to use is determined at runtime, so a pool is configured to provide the right one:

```
class Things(a: ThingA, b: ThingB) {
  addThing(a)
  addThing(b)

  def getThing(x: String) = { ... }
}
```

How do I provide all configured `Thing`s to the ThingPool without explicitly adding it to the constructor?

As in, I'd like to do the following:

```
class Things(pool: ThingPool) {
  addThingsFromPool(pool)

  def getThing(x: String) = { ... }
}
```

... where `ThingPool` has all `Thing`s without explicitly asking for them.

... or, `ThingPool` could be a `List[Thing]`.

The current state of things requires **two** additional edits to add a `Thing`. I'd like to get to the point where all I need to do is add the binding statement in my Guice module.

*I have omitted the annotations for clarity.*

Comment: I guess it's at odds with your wish, but have you looked into using the Cake Pattern instead of an extra-linguistic DI tool such as Guice?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for the Multibinding extension: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Multibindings

```
val thingBinder = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), classOf[Thing])
thingBinder.addBinding().to(classOf[ThingA])
thingBinder.addBinding().to(classOf[ThingA])
```

And then to use it

```
class Things(pool:Set[Thing])
```